# How to query tree structure recursively with MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, recursion

For example a tree structure as;

```
[
    {id: 1 , childrenIdList: [2, 3]},
    {id: 2 , childrenIdList: [4, 5]},
    {id: 3 , childrenIdList: []},
    {id: 4 , childrenIdList: [6, 7]},
    {id: 5 , childrenIdList: []},
    {id: 6 , childrenIdList: []},
    {id: 7 , childrenIdList: []}
]
```

which is like;

```
               1
          2        3
       4    5
    6    7
```

How can I trace tree from starting the leaf node(id=7) to root(id=1)?

Finding the parent of `id=7` is easy as;

```
db.document.find({childrenList: { $in: [7]}}, {id: 1}).toArray(function(err), result{
  /*result gives 
  {"id" : NumberInt(4)}
  now I should look the parent of id=4, and parent of id=2 as you know.
  */
})
```

Is recursive queries possible on mongodb? How can I implement it?

Comment: Look at Graph data: https://www.compose.com/articles/graph-data-with-mongodb/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on your use case, [MongoDB v3.4](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center) provides an [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) operator called [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/). The aggregation operator is able to perform a recursive search on a collection. See more definiton on [$graphLookup definition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#pipe._S_graphLookup).

Using your documents hierarchy and values above as examples, you could try running below aggregation:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([

                {$unwind:{
                        path:"$childrenIdList", 
                        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}
                  }, 
                {$graphLookup:{
                        from:"collectionName", 
                        startWith:"$_id", 
                        connectFromField:"_id", 
                        connectToField:"childrenIdList", 
                        as:"myparents",  
                        restrictSearchWithMatch: {"_id"}}
                  }, 
                {$match: {"_id": 7 } },
                {$group:{
                        _id:"$_id", 
                        parents:{$addToSet:"$myparents._id"}
                  }}
]);
```

The above should return result as below:

```
{ "_id" : 7, "parents" : [ [ 1, 2, 4 ] ] }
```

Having said that, if you have a large collection the above query may not be performant as you'll be performing [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on each documents and won't be able to utilise indexes. As suggested by others, you should re-consider your document model structure. See [Data Models Tree Structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/). Optimise based on your application logic and querying use case, and let the flexible document schema follow.